# How much of Drupal 8 will rely on or be compatible with Symfony?

Tags: 8, theming

Now that Drupal 8 is being redeveloped with [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), and we are just about to go into the [code freeze](http://buytaert.net/updated-drupal-8-release-schedule) so that early adopters can start playing with it, what will it affect?

Will we be able to write modules and themes like writing bundles? Should we all start brushing up on or learning [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)?

Comment: That is an outdated timeline. Code freeze is now July 1, 2013: http://buytaert.net/drupal-8-feature-freeze-extended

Answer (score 7):

Symfony, as in full stack Symfony, we aren't to be compatible with.

We are using Symfony components so many concepts used there will be useful.