# Should I learn Symfony 2?

Tags: 8

I saw this,  [How much of Drupal 8 will rely on or be compatible with Symfony?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68134/how-much-of-drupal-8-will-rely-on-or-be-compatible-with-symfony) but I don't understand if it applies to my question.  Should I learn Symfony 2 to develop with Drupal?

Comment: Read [this](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) immediately if you haven't already :)

Comment: @Clive I was searching Symfony 2 and DI, found it, and then stumbled upon the Symfony 2 Drupal 8 subject.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Symfony 2, as in the full stack Symfony 2 has no bearing on Drupal 8 -- we do not use its bundles, we do not use the same routing as Symfony does (we use a botched up work on top called Symfony CMF which is made less dog slow by bastardizing my menu work on top of it but it's <del>still undocumented</del>, incomprehensible, does not yield to static code analysis tools and altogether is broken and slow). We do not use the same ORM (Doctrine). We are using *some* Symfony 2 components however there is very little visible of it to the "end" developer. For example, confusingly enough, *sometimes* you need to use events (what was hook_boot/hook_init in D7 is replaced by Symfony HTTP kernel events) whereas most often Drupal still uses its hooks. Confusing is the name of the game where Symfony 2 interacts with Drupal. It's an extremely poor fit and the (non)amount of the documentation of how this fit (does not) happen makes it even harder.

Edit: we do use the service container http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html at least the static parts of it -- *however* dynamic service additions and alterations are done via Drupal specific means (service providers which attaches to the system via a special magic way which is neither events nor hooks. Welcome to Drupal 8.)

So: if you know Symfony 2 inside and out then a little of that will be usable in Drupal 8. If you don't then don't bother with Symfony 2 books or tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your many contributions chx, and dare I say _honest_ perspective on Symfony 2 usage D8; and the new APIs available in D8.

Comment: Don't take this wrong, but who is "we"? Are you on the Drupal core team?

Comment: lol @johnny. chx has been foundational. You ought to just do something like search drupal.org before that kinda question: https://drupal.org/user/9446

Comment: @Mixologic It's not personal.  I said don't take it wrong.  I was curious if chx was part of the core team.  Chx spoke with authority.  I wanted to take it as such and not waste my time worrying about Symfony 2.

Comment: @johnny: sorry I didnt mean to come across snarky. More like astonished that somebody didn't know who chx was. I too, didnt know who chx was for a long time.  I was trying to show you that a great way to determine somebodies credibility/authority in the Drupal Community is to check out their user page on drupal.org.

Comment: There is no "core team". Anyone can contribute to core (and they are welcome for it). I had my share of contributions to core in the past (had most core patches for D5,D6, 4th most for D7), right now I am down to just migrate and after that, likely nothing.

Comment: @Mixologic Thanks.  I really never look at people's user pages.  I read it.  Thanks chx.

Comment: Does "botched up work on top called Symfony CMF which is made less dog slow by bastardizing my menu work on top of it" still apply, or was it just a temporary thing in the migration to the new code?

Comment: It still applies. There's some documentation now as dawehner points out.

Comment: @chx Do you think it is now safe to develop on Drupal 8 and expect very little change to the core?  I saw only 12 critical issues remain; hopefully plugin development wouldn't change if I started now in 2015.  Thanks for input.

Comment: Anyone have an update on this?  Did Drupal 8 become more "Symfony"-esk, since the initial answer?  Does Symfony 3 have any bearing on Drupal 8?

Answer (score 6):

I "grew up" on Drupal so I was always procedural guy(Drupal is my main/only tool for making websites which is my job). At first I was very confused when I started to use Drupal 8. The OOP wasn't that hard since I knew OOP, but the new architecture was hard to get my head around. But after two weeks I started to feel like home again. This website and #drupal-contribute helped me a lot. I've read some information from Symfony documentation to understand controllers basically and no I'm working with D8 for 4 months and I feel like home again.

Things have changed but you'll learn the new ways very fast. You really don' have to learn Symfony AT ALL. I didn't.

One thing that made things MUCH easier for me was switching my IDE from NetBeans to PHPStorm because NetBeans didn't supported browsing inherited methods. After few months I cannot understand how was I able to use NB :) (though working with Git in NB is for me much better)

So to answer your question: you absolutely don't have to learn Symfony. To meake your life easier look at *.services.yml files in modules(that implements them) and also route callbacks in any modules *.routing.yml file to understand page callbacks(from hook_menu in D7).

Comment: Do you think learning to develop in 7 will be useful in 8?

Comment: Well, you'll have to learn Drupal's concepts anyway so it really doesn't matter. They still apply in D8. Though if you're starting just now I don't see any point in going back to D7.

Comment: hi, I've worked with drupal 7 around 4 years now and recently I want to learn drupal8, I don't know where to start, what did you mean by #drupal-contribute @IvanJaros ?